# Special operator - in bash

Tags: bash, cron, stdin

I notice a usage of crontab

```
crontab -
```

If I echo some content in this command, it is able to overwrite the cron content, e.g.,

```
$ crontab -l
...
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /bin/ls
$ crontab -l | sed 's/ls/cd/g' | crontab -
$ crontab -l
...
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /bin/cd
```

Question:
What does '-' mean in bash? Is '-' something generic in bash?

Comment: It's not an operator; it's a conventional file name.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123467/accidentally-typed-crontab-with-just-the-dash/123468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` is not specific to bash. It is a convention used with many unix programs as a file to mean "stdin" (for input) or "stdout" (for output).

In this case, `crontab` normally takes a parameter that is the filename to read and load as the new cron content. Instead, passing `-` means "take the content from standard input".

Answer (score 1):

From the crontab manpage `man crontab`:

> The  first  form of this command is used to install a new crontab from
>   some named file or standard input if
>          the pseudo-filename "-" is given.

So that `-` is replaced by stdin (what you piped to it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am taking the other answer since it can also be used as stdout.